# Relating moments of random variables and tightness of of the distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given a set of random variables and measures $\{X_n , \mu_n\}$ does the behaviour of the $p$th moment ($\mathbb{E} [ \vert X_n\vert ^p]$) for some $p$ have any relation to whether or not $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight?

Answer (score 2):

If $E[|X_n|] \le M$ for all $n$, the sequence is tight by the Markov inequality:
$$P(|X_n| > K) \le E[|X_n|]/K \le \frac{M}{K}$$

Choosing $K$ sufficiently big yields the assertion.

Note that the uniform boundedness of any $p$-th absolute moment for $p > 1$ also yields the uniform boundedness of the first absolute moment by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: What is the definition of tightness you are using? I am having a hard time relating your definition to say the one given here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures  (...for one thing you need to build the "n" independence somewhere in your argument!..)

Comment: The bound $M$ is uniform in $n$, which is why the bound is independent of $n$. Note that the set $S = \{ x \mid |x| \le K\}$ is compact and satisfies $\mu_n(\Omega \setminus S) = P(|X| > K) \le \frac{M}{K}$. Now choosing $K = \frac{M}{\varepsilon}$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ shows the tightness of the measures.

Comment: By the Wikipedia definition we need the compact set $K_\epsilon$ to be independent of $n$. The corresponding $K_\epsilon$ for you seems to be $\{ x s.t \vert X_n(x)\vert \leq K\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. This set is clearly $n$ dependent.

Comment: No, the set is $\{x \mid |x| \le K\}$. You seem to mix up the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ on which $X_n$ is defined and the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ on which $\mu_n = P^X$ is defined. In my last comment I actually meant $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}\setminus S)$ and not $\mu_n(\Omega \setminus S)$ - this is my mistake.

Comment: Why is $\mu_n ( x s.t \vert x \vert \leq K ) \geq \frac{M}{K} $ ? This is not what Markov gave you.

Comment: I guess the $P$in the Markov is $\mu_n$. Then Markov basically says that, $\mu_n \{ x \mid \vert X_n(x)\vert > K\} \leq M/K$.

Comment: Your first inequality is incorrect. Markov states $\mu_n(\{x \mid |x| > K\}) = P(|X_n| > K) \le \frac{M}{K}$

Comment: So this is what I am missing! Why is $P( \vert X_n\vert > K) $ the same as $\mu_n \{ x \mid \vert x \vert > K \}$ ? I would have thought it means $\mu_n \{ x \mid \vert X_n(x) \vert > K \}$

Comment: $X_n$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $X_n(x)$ doesn't make sense for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. $\mu_n$ is the push-forwars measure of $P$ under $X_n$, i.e. $\mu_n(A) = P(X_n^{-1}(A))$ by definition.

Comment: This is confusing! For our "push forward" to make sense we need $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Only then does $X_n^{-1}(A)$ make sense. But then to start off $\mu_n$ was the measure defined on the domain of $X_n$ i.e $\Omega$. So $\mu_n(A)$ doesn't make sense! Also way you have defined it seems that $P$ is a measure on $\Omega$!

Comment: $\mu_n$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$ the domain of $X_n$. So we need to define a $K_\epsilon \subset \Omega$. But if you define $K_\epsilon = \{ x \mid \vert x \vert \leq K \}$ then $K_\epsilon \subset \mathbb{R}$. How does this make sense?

Comment: What is $\mu_n$ then supposed to be? I supposed that it was the distribution of $X_n$, otherwise I don't see any connection between the random variable and the measure.

Comment: So I guess to make sense of it we need all the random variables to be defined w.r.t the same measure P but they induce different measures on $\mathbb{R}$ via this push-forward of $P$ w.r.t $X_n$. Right?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Actually, no, each $X_n$ may be defined on a specific probability space $(\Omega_n,\mathcal F_n,P_n)$ but every $X_n$ must be a random variable with values in the same measurable space, say $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$. Then each $\mu_n=P_n\circ X_n^{-1}$ is a measure on $(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$ and the tightness of the family $(\mu_n)$ of distributions indeed means $$\forall\epsilon\quad\exists K\quad\forall n\quad\mu_n(\{x\in\mathbb R^d\mid \|x\|\geqslant K\})\leqslant\epsilon$$ ((To be explicit, every other comment from Dominik before the "Yes" one is correct.))